# Yii2 проблема с реляции hasMany

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Помогите с решение проблемы.
Есть таблица Статей (Articles) и таблица особых меток (routeTypeRelation) у статьи. У статьи может быть одна метка, может быть несколько, а может вообще не быть. Делаю реляцию через joinWith но получается, что если нет нечего в таблице меток то статьи не выбираются. Если убрать условие в реляции то тогда всё хорошо, но условие мне нужно обязательно иначе он мне выберет все метки из таблицы.
По факту надо выбирать все статьи в независимости есть метки или нет.

```
$query = Articles::find()
            ->joinWith('district0')
            ->joinWith('region0')
            ->joinWith('routeTypeRelation as rtr')
            ->where(['active' => self::ACTIVE ])
            ->groupBy('rtr.object_id');
```

Связь

```
public function getRouteTypeRelation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RouteTypeRelation::className(), ['object_id' => 'id'])->andWhere('object_type = :articles',[':articles' => 'articles']);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение

```
public function getRouteTypeRelation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RouteTypeRelation::className(), ['object_id' => 'id'])->onCondition(['object_type' => 'articles']);
    }
```

И надо поменять группировку

```
 $query = Articles::find()
            ->joinWith('routeTypeRelation as rtr')
            ->joinWith('district0')
            ->joinWith('region0')
            ->where(['active' => self::ACTIVE ])
            ->groupBy('articles.id');
```